# Why can I not use the call function or use my sub procedure in vb.net?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to make some code for two projects and both of them have problems with the sub procedures. I keep getting the same answer on which it tells me that they are not declared. This is what I don't understand as it looks like I already declared them in my Sub Main.
Here are my two codes..
[My First code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVR4q.png)

[The error I get on my first code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FFNF.png)

[My Second code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H92zS.png)

[The error I get on my second code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhGgC.png)

Thanks.

I tried to use Call feature on the second one but it didn't work.

Comment: I just realised that the arrays are wrong in my first code... ignore that =P

Comment: First off, please don't post images of the code.  Just plan makes it hard for people to help so they won't.  Next, the IDE is actually telling you exactly what is wrong.  You are attempting to call methods that require parameters but not supplying them in the calls.    Either update the methods so paramaters are not required, or add the parameters.

Comment: And how do I add the parameters? ByRef?

Comment: _And how do I add the parameters_  Really?  Sorry, guessing you're new to programming but really this is a pretty fundamental thing to know.  There are plenty of tutorials and examples on the web.  Will also pay you learn the difference between ByRef and ByVal parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at your second error : sub todecimal require 2 args and you call it with only one so error.
anyway your code is confused.
first remove this declarations

```
dim number,values as integer
dim hexstring as string
```

after sub Main(....)

change

```
values = todecimal(hexstring)
```

to

```
values = todecimal(hexdigit)
```

in for/next loop

at end, change sub declaration to

```
sub todecimal(byref hexdigit as integer)
```

values is not needed because allready declared as global